# Getting first 3 letters of first and last name

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first google app question.  I would appreciate any help.  I did try searching for similar questions, but because my knowledge is basic, it's hard to adapt an "almost the same" question... so please forgive me to asking my own.

If I take my name, Daniel Bonallack in cell A1, I want to convert that to BON_DAN and set that to a variable.

So,

- First 3 letters of last name
- First 3 letters of first name
- underscore between them
- all capitalized

I have this basic code:

```
  var vv = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();

  var firstName = vv.substring(0, 3)
```

Which gives me the first 3 letters of the active cell.  And that's as far as I got.  Can someone help?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`String.toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

```js
const name = "Daniel Bonallack";
const abb = name.replace(/(\w{1,3})\w*\s+(\w{1,3})\w*/,"$2_$1").toUpperCase();
console.log(abb)
```

- \w:  letter(`w`ord)
- \s:  space

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: Hi - This is working for me well, except for names that only have 3 letters.  For example, it doesn't work for "JEN SANDMAN".  Would you be able to help me modify this so that it works for size name?  For example, "Daniel Bonallack" would return BON_DAN, "Jen Sandman" would return SAN_JEN,  "Xu Win" would return WIN_XU, and "Simon Li" would return "LI_SIM".  Thank yuou

Comment: @Daniel Take the [tour]. You should press the correct button on the left of my answer.

Comment: If I have a follow-up, as above, do I resubmit a question?

Comment: @Daniel It's better to ask a new question for new queries/follow ups. However, in this case, I already edited my answer, if you haven't noticed.

Comment: Oh dear.  I'm making a mess of this.  I just posted a new question.  Thank you for your time, and sorry to have missed this.